# laravel array validation under array

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-8

i have array from post request

```
 #parameters: array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "aXtlqdZWcz5lbLyZGn88PJB5oADF9oZz6k2c7PwW"
  "spg" => "test"
  "nama" => "user"
  "hp" => "12345678"
  "alamat" => "surabaya"
  "orderProducts" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "product_id" => "1"
      "quantity" => "1"
```

how can i validate orderProduct->product_id = "required" and orderProduct->quantity = "min:1"

and this is my $request->validation

```
$request->validate([
        'spg' => 'required|max:30',
        'nama' => 'required|max:30',
        'hp' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:8,15',
        'alamat' => 'required|max:255',
        'orderProducts.product_id' => 'required',
        'orderProducts.quantity' => 'required|min:1'
    ]);
```

very grateful if someone help to solve my problem. thanks

Comment: what did you tried so far? update that code also

Comment: okay I have included the validation code

Comment: just want validate request data before store to database

Comment: so you are passing array of objects in OrderProducts right?

Comment: yaaaa that's right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$request->validate([
    'spg' => 'required|max:30',
    'nama' => 'required|max:30',
    'hp' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:8,15',
    'alamat' => 'required|max:255',
    'orderProducts.*.product_id' => 'required',
    'orderProducts.*.quantity' => 'required|min:1'
])
```

You can Refer [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays)

Comment: @Reynaldo `'orderProducts.*.product_id' => 'required',` the OrderProducts is the key and `*` is the index